# Swing Button Invisible until actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Is it possible to create a button that won't be seen until the user clicks another button?

My goal is for the button to be invisible by default rather than when its clicked on. Then become visible when another action is performed. The code below is my original attempt at creating this.

```
public void but_roll1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    if (!bal_but.isEnabled() && !gamble_but.isEnabled()) {
        but_roll1.setVisible(true);
        but_roll1.setEnabled(true);         
        d1 = diceRoll();
        die1_display.setText(String.valueOf(d1));  
        but_roll1.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        but_roll1.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should work.  You may need to `.invalidate()` the layout or parent container to let the system know the button needs to be checked again an drawn.

Comment: Works fine for me. Post an [mcve] demonstrating the problem. The problem may be elsewhere in your code. For example, maybe the panel isn't large enough to display the button.

Comment: Two better strategies: 1) Make the button disabled until the first button is clicked. 2) Put the button in a `CardLayout` with a second blank panel till needed.

Answer (score 2):

Two better strategies:

1. Put the button in a `CardLayout` with a second blank panel till needed.
2. Make the button disabled until the first button is clicked.

I prefer the 2nd as the 'path of least surprise' for the user. YMMV.

### Initial view

[image]

### View after 'effect' button actioned

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ButtonNotUsableTillAction {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    ButtonNotUsableTillAction() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        
        // first demo, using card layout
        JPanel cardDemoPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 2, 2));
        cardDemoPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Card Layout"));
        ui.add(cardDemoPanel);
        
        JButton actionCardButton = new JButton("Action");
        cardDemoPanel.add(actionCardButton);
        
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        cardDemoPanel.add(cardLayoutPanel);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(new JPanel(), "panel");
        cardLayoutPanel.add(new JButton("Effect"), "button");
        cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel, "panel");
        
        ActionListener flipCardListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel, "button");
            }
        };
        actionCardButton.addActionListener(flipCardListener);
        
        // first demo, using disabled / enabled
        JPanel enabledDemoPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 2, 2));
        enabledDemoPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Enabled"));
        ui.add(enabledDemoPanel);
        JButton actionEnabledButton = new JButton("Action");
        enabledDemoPanel.add(actionEnabledButton);
        JButton effectButton = new JButton("Effect");
        enabledDemoPanel.add(effectButton);
        effectButton.setEnabled(false);
        ActionListener enableComponentListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                effectButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        actionEnabledButton.addActionListener(enableComponentListener);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ButtonNotUsableTillAction o = new ButtonNotUsableTillAction();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @markspace mentioned, you need to revalidate the button's container after setting the button visible:

```
but_roll1.getParent().revalidate();
```

Comment: You don't need to revalidate() the parent. When a property on a Swing component is changed the component will invoke revalidate() and repaint() on itself.